# Creating proper CSS Columns with Div tag inside bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<!-- Blog Post -->
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/948D/production/_109592083_mediaitem109591445.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Funding For Bulbul</h2>
                    <p class="card-text">The authorities in Bangladesh have ordered the evacuation of some 100,000 people from coastal areas as Cyclone Bulbul is set to hit the country.

                        The storm - which is due to make landfall on Saturday evening local time - is expected to unleash surges as high as 7ft (two metres).</p>
                  <div class ="myrow">
                      <div class = "col-1">
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                    </div> 
                    <!--Progress Bar-->
                   <div class = "col-2">
                    <div class="container">

                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    Posted on November 9 , 2019 by
                    <a href="https://www.bbc.com/bengali">BBC Bangladesh</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**The Corresponding CSS File**

```
  .myrow {
 display :flex;
 width : 100%;
  }

  .col-1 {
       float : left;
      width : 40% !important;

  }
.col-2 {
    float : left;
    width : 60% !important;

  }
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

**Output :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASN45.jpg

I want the buttons to be perfectly visible, the size of the button seems small , Want it to fit the text. How can I Fix this!

**Update 1 ** :

Updated CSS :

```
   .myrow {
 display :flex;
 width : 100%;
  }

  .col-1my {

      width : 40% !important;

  }
.col-2my {

    width : 60% !important;

  }
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Fixed it from using modified column name & not using float with flex from the comments. The first part was showing wrong due to the css was directly modifying the columns of the bootstrap but after renaming the column it was more precise and the issue got fixed

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, why are you using your own row and column classes? Also why are you using float with flex?  Finally, I wouldn't use col-1 and col-2 as you are overriding bootstraps col-1 and col-2 classes

Comment: Use `input-group` of bootstrap

Comment: I copied the Card template from bootstrap, but want to add a progress bar inside it ! So to allign it side by side I tried to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML Like & Remove your custom CSS

```
  <div class="card mb-4">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/948D/production/_109592083_mediaitem109591445.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">Funding For Bulbul</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
            The authorities in Bangladesh have ordered the evacuation of some 100,000 people from coastal areas as Cyclone Bulbul is set to hit the country.

            The storm - which is due to make landfall on Saturday evening local time - is expected to unleash surges as high as 7ft (two metres).
        </p>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><!-- Changes HERE -->
            <div class=""><!-- Changes HERE -->
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <!--Progress Bar-->
            <div class="flex-fill"><!-- Changes HERE -->
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        Posted on November 9 , 2019 by
        <a href="https://www.bbc.com/bengali">BBC Bangladesh</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/2yzw4Ljv/4/